# what's the difference between mind and brain?

Tags: word-choice

—Is Mr. Black a successful businessman? 
—Yes, he is a _mind__ and he set up his own company by himself. A. brain B. helpful man C. smart person

I think both A and C can replace "mind". they can both mean "intelligent person"

Comment: Welcome to the community, I hope you can find the answer to all of your questions here. Before asking a question it would be a good idea to do some research first, and share it with people here so that they can better help you find an answer to your question . Check out sources like, dictionaries, Google Ngram and credible Grammar websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use it that way. This dictionary describes the use as "informal"
[American Heritage Dictionary "brain" 3c](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=brain)

The word "mind" itself wouldn't be used as it is in the test question. One can describe a person as "a great mind", but not as just "a mind". There's no reason other than established usage.

Comment: many thanks for helping with this. Got it.